# Data imputation with mtsdi package R

Tags: r, statistics, missing-data, normal-distribution, mle

I found the package mtsdi and the corresponding function mnimput:
[R Documentation](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/mtsdi/html/mnimput.html)
This function gives very good results for my data sets. However, I would like to understand the mathematical background of the function. I am familiar with the EM algorithm but how exactly does the function work? How are splines used here and is there a connection with the algorithm derived by Schafer?

Comment: This is a better question for CrossValidated, StackOverflow is only for programming questions not mathematical or statistical theory.

Comment: The manual (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mtsdi/mtsdi.pdf) has several references, including Junger, W.L. and Ponce de Leon, A. (2015) Imputation of Missing Data in Time Series for Air
Pollutants. Atmospheric Environment, 102, 96-104.

Comment: Yes, but what is the basis of the derivation from 2.1: Imputation procedure. Is there a source that derives it in more detail?